# Looking for a complement that means "sucks it up"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I am writing a review, and am looking to convey a sense that, even though my report may not agree with, or have reservations about an aspect of their job, they `suck it up`, and carry out their job duties.

I see a few posts on [this phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32560/what-does-suck-it-up-and-go-mean), but they don't provide alternatives (the ones I've looked at were asking more about meaning vs synonyms).

**EDIT**:  I wasn't clear enough that I'd like to emphasize the positive aspect of this, and just use words/phrases with positive connotations; that reflect that they're accepting this unpleasant aspect without complaints.

Comment: Reasonable alternatives are certainly given at [What does “suck it up and go” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32560/what-does-suck-it-up-and-go-mean) Synonyms are what we normally use to give meanings.

Comment: Related if not dup:  [Word for not being happy with something but having to be satisfied with it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38719/word-for-not-being-happy-with-something-but-having-to-be-satisfied-with-it/38825#38825)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to "*They suck it up*"I would use another idiomatic expression : "*They just put up with it*". The addition of "**just*" to "*put up with it*" (which is referred to in the given links) gives a feeling of being obliged to tolerate things, of having no real choice in the matter.

Comment: This is along the right line, but I'd prefer not to emphasize `they have no choice in the matter`, and focus on the fact that they accept it without making a big issue out of it.  I'll edit the question to emphasize I'd like to phrase things in a positive light.